# Android: Gap between CardView elements in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-cardview

I can't seem to increase the gap between the CardView elements in my ListView. I tried adding `android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"` to the CardView but that doesn't do anything. I'me using SDK 23. Any Idea what I can do?

Here is the card layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" <!-- Not Working -->
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:contentPadding="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_dato"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tip_detail_date"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_tip_dato"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change yout listview some thing like this

```
 <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/ListView01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/redBackground"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip">// Increase this height as your need
 </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/matrix"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#f6f6f6"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0.7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0.7dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

If you increase the cardElevation or marginBottom gap will be increased.

Answer (score -1):

For Api 23. you need to set

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

in your card view

Comment: Then try adding this: card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"